# Weak linking to support previous iOS versions

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm trying to support older iOS versions in my app. I initially thought I only have to set those frameworks to "weak linking" that are not present in the older OS, e.g. the iAd framework. And then make sure that I don't call unsupported APIs in the code. However, when I try to run the app (which is compiled with the most recent framework) in the old simulator, it crashes during startup with a message similar to

```
18/07/2010 11:07:29 UIKitApplication:xxxxx[0xe006][5729]    dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSAssertionHandler
18/07/2010 11:07:29 UIKitApplication:xxxxx[0xe006][5729]      Referenced from: xxxxx/Applications/23CE4978-D25F-4DB4-A486-0730EBBB501B/xxxxx.app/xxxxx
18/07/2010 11:07:29 UIKitApplication:xxxxx[0xe006][5729]      Expected in: /Xcode3.1.4/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.1.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
18/07/2010 11:07:29 UIKitApplication:xxxxx[0xe006][5729]     in xxxxx/Applications/23CE4978-D25F-4DB4-A486-0730EBBB501B/xxxxx.app/xxxxx
```

After setting *all* frameworks to weak linking, I still get an error message:

```
18/07/2010 11:33:32 UIKitApplication:xxxxx[0xc4a7][8204]    dyld: Symbol not found: __objc_empty_vtable
18/07/2010 11:33:32 UIKitApplication:xxxxx[0xc4a7][8204]      Referenced from: xxxxx/Applications/23CE4978-D25F-4DB4-A486-0730EBBB501B/xxxxx.app/xxxxx
18/07/2010 11:33:32 UIKitApplication:xxxxx[0xc4a7][8204]      Expected in: /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the solution (**please can someone confirm this?**):

You cannot use the simulator to test if your apps run with a previous iOS version. It only works on the device, according to [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross%5Fdevelopment/Configuring/configuring.html):

> **iPhone OS Note:** Mac OS X v10.6 does not support using iPhone
>   Simulator SDKs prior to version 3.0.
>   In addition, when building with the
>   simulator SDKs, the binary runs only
>   on the same OS version as the SDK, not
>   on earlier or later versions.

This seems really dull. How am I supposed to test backwards compatibility without having one physical iPhone for each SDK version? Not good.

Comment: Pssst... Install an old SDK in a separate directory so you can use an old simulator :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the new class directly if you want to support old platforms.  Instead, you use `NSClassFromString` like so:

```
class myClass = NSClassFromString(@"NSCoolNewClass");
if (myClass) 
    //do stuff
```

Comment: Yeah.. I'm doing that for the new classes. But `NSAssertionHandler` (see error message above) is present in the SDK since version 2.0 and part of CoreFoundation.